# Issue with eloquent Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a problem with Eloquent, how to show the sum of products with 0 purchase price.

my model invoice and method products

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withPivot('quantity', 'product_name', 'net_unit_price', 'gross_unit_price', 'purchase_price');

}
```

my model products and method invoice

```
public function invoices()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Invoice::class);
}
```

and I need sum - net_unit_price from invoices sold in this month for eg

```
$sellMonthReplace = $user->invoices()
        ->with(['products' => function ($query) {
            $query->wherePivot('purchase_price', '=', '0');
        }])
        ->whereNull('parent_id')
        ->where('incoming', '=', '0')
        ->whereNull('is_proforma')
        ->where('sell_date', '>', $now->format('Y-m-01'))
        ->sum('net_value');
```

but this isn't working.

this below work well but is raw SQL and I don`t know how do it in eloquent

```
select SUM(invoice_product.net_unit_price*invoice_product.quantity)
from homestead.invoices  
join homestead.invoice_product on invoice_product.invoice_id = invoices.id
where invoices.sell_date > 2019-03-01
and invoices.incoming = 0
and invoices.parent_id is null
and invoices.is_proforma is null
and invoice_product.`purchase_price` = 0
```

anybody could help me? thank you in advance

Comment: We didnt see the whole image 
i mean we didnt know what this relation you try to make 
so i just try to help by another way 
Check every eloquent you made for example 


```$sellMonthReplace = $user->invoices()
        ->with(['products' => function ($query) {
            $query->wherePivot('purchase_price', '=', '0');
        }]);```


and check the another one until you know what is the problem if your problem in sum only then its easy way to detect it :D i hope it solve your problem

Comment: after this part of eloquent in dd I have {HasMany {#530 ▼
  #foreignKey: "invoices.user_id"
  #localKey: "id"
  #query: Builder {#531 ▶}
  #parent: User {#528 ▶}
  #related: Invoice {#532 ▶}
}} so I assume I have problem because I don't have belongsToMany and I can't search after pivot?

Comment: I need data from $invoice->products but when I have $user->invoices->products I don't have capabilities to take information from product hmm I'am puzzled

Comment: Please add the `User::invoices()` relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to cut your query short to make sure that your relations are working?

Also is the $user variable filled properly ?

What does a dump of the $sellMonthReplace return to you?

Comment: "218.00" this is my dd so we have amount but its not correct value, because I need value from pivot - net_unit_price not from net_value from invoices and you have right when I use $user->invoices() I have problem with products and how manage pivot data. I need sum of any sell products with purchase 0

Comment: ```I need value from pivot - net_unit_price not from net_value from invoice``` and you just say ``` ->sum('net_value');``` try ```->sum('net_unit_price');```

Comment: I tried this but I have error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'net_unit_price' in 'field list' (SQL: select sum(`net_unit_price`) as aggregate from `invoices` where `invoices`.`user_id` = 9 and `invoices`.`user_id` is not null and `parent_id` is null and `incoming` = 0 and `is_proforma` is null and `sell_date` > 2019-03-01)